# Installing xorg-x11-server-Xvfb broke X and uninstalling it doesn't fix it

Tags: x11

I have a user who requested that I install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb to see if he could run Python/selenium headless. Unfortunately, this experiment did not work and normal x2go connections also stopped working. I uninstalled xorg-x11-server-Xvfb but unfortunately, that does not seem to have fixed it. Any ideas what configuration file I need to revert to its previous state?  Our workstation is running RHEL6.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with configuration files. It's more likely that the installation of xvfb pulled in some dependencies, and that it's those dependencies which cause the problem. When you removed when, the dependencies were not removed along with it, meaning the problem wasn't fixed.

Check your `yum.log`, and look for the transaction where you installed xvfb. Check what other packages were installed along with it. Remove them. That should fix your problem.

Comment: No, I had already checked the yum.log and all of its dependencies were already installed.